# applying the pvclust R function to a precomputed dist object

Tags: r, pvclust

I'm using R to perform an hierarchical clustering. As a first approach I used `hclust` and performed the following steps:

1. I imported the distance matrix
2. I used the `as.dist` function to transform it in a `dist` object
3. I run `hclust` on the `dist` object

Here's the R code:

```
distm <- read.csv("distMatrix.csv")
d <- as.dist(distm)
hclust(d, "ward")
```

At this point I would like to do something similar with the function `pvclust`; however, I cannot because it's not possible to pass a precomputed `dist` object. How can I proceed considering that I'm using a distance not available among those provided by the `dist` function of R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you only have a distance matrix, or you computed it beforehand. In the former case, as already suggested by @Vincent, it would not be too difficult to tweak the R code of `pvclust` itself (using `fix()` or whatever; I provided some hints on [another question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10349/930)). In the latter case, the authors of [pvclust](http://www.is.titech.ac.jp/~shimo/prog/pvclust/) provide an [example](http://www.is.titech.ac.jp/~shimo/prog/pvclust/pvclust_unofficial_090824/readme.txt) on how to use a custom distance function, although that means you will have to install their "unofficial version".

Comment: I've seen the unofficial version, however I would prefer to avoid using it... After posting on stackoverflow I contacted the author of the pvclust function. This is his answer: Since pvclust uses a bootstrap-based algorithm, using precomputed dist
object is impossible in principle. I'm sorry I cannot be of help.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested the suggestion of Vincent, you can do the following (my data set is a dissimilarity matrix):

```
# Import you data
distm <- read.csv("distMatrix.csv")
d <- as.dist(distm)

# Compute the eigenvalues
x <- cmdscale(d,1,eig=T)

# Plot the eigenvalues and choose the correct number of dimensions (eigenvalues close to 0)
plot(x$eig, 
   type="h", lwd=5, las=1, 
   xlab="Number of dimensions", 
   ylab="Eigenvalues")

# Recover the coordinates that give the same distance matrix with the correct number of dimensions    
x <- cmdscale(d,nb_dimensions)

# As mentioned by Stéphane, pvclust() clusters columns
pvclust(t(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the dataset is not too large, you can embed your n points in a space of dimension n-1, with the same distance matrix.

```
# Sample distance matrix
n <- 100
k <- 1000
d <- dist( matrix( rnorm(k*n), nc=k ), method="manhattan" )

# Recover some coordinates that give the same distance matrix
x <- cmdscale(d, n-1)
stopifnot( sum(abs(dist(x) - d)) < 1e-6 )

# You can then indifferently use x or d
r1 <- hclust(d)
r2 <- hclust(dist(x)) # identical to r1
library(pvclust)
r3 <- pvclust(x)
```

If the dataset is large, you may have to check how `pvclust` is implemented.

Comment: In retrospect (i.e., after having replied myself), I believe the OP really wants to pass a distance matrix to `pvclust`, whereas `pvclust` expects a data.frame or matrix object.

Comment: Be careful: pvclust() clusters columns, not rows, hence the good code is pvclust(t(x)), not pvclust(x)